# Codeigniter Error 500 in subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, subdomain, http-status-code-500

So, I recently installed codeigniter in a subdomain and I'm getting 500 error when I try to access it. Script should run normal, I had it on several other domains and my guess it's htaccess on the main domain folder (public_html).

Here's the .htaccess from the "root" folder

```
#OLD
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.tv$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.tv$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^db\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://domain.com/blog/topics/vidcast/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*$
RewriteRule ^blog/index.php/archives/category/podcast/feed$ http://feeds.feedburner.com/domainPodcast [R=301,L]

#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www|ftp|webmail)\.milaraki\.com
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.domain\.com
#RewriteRule (.*) http://domain.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/%1/$1 [L]

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

And here's the .htaccess in the subdomain (named: db.domain.com)

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_-]+)\.html$ index.php/page/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|asset|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Now, whenever I try to access "http://db.domain.com", it redirects me to "http://db.domain.com/blog/". If I try to access by subfolder
like "http://domain.com/db" it give's me an 500Error.

We also get these spam of lines in apache/error_log:

```
warn] (103)Software caused connection abort: mod_fcgid: ap_pass_brigade failed in handle_request function
```

Also, let me tell you it's in a VPS and the "root" .htaccess file it's not made by me, but from the client, all I have done, it's to add an extra line in his .htaccess file to "stop" the redirect but it's not working at all.
That's the line I added (already in the code i posted)

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^db.domain.com$ [NC]
```

It still gives the error even if I remove it or leave it there.
Oh and, in the "root" folder, he installed WordPress.

Hope I was clear enough, feel free to ask me other questions.

Comment: remove RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/ and try

Comment: @DevidasKadam Well, i completely commented out that section `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>....</IfModule>` Looks like it works, although now i need to add `index.php` to the url, in my other domains, i never had to use that...
In `config.php` i have set `$config['index_page'] = '';`

Comment: you don't need to set `$config['index_page'] ;` keep it blank

Comment: @DevidasKadam I've set it as blank. Still, whenever i manually type it, i get the login page of the script, but i dont want to use `index.php` at all.

Comment: you know the blog folder is directly pointed to subdomain, you dont need to keep .htaccess in public_html. keep a normal .thacces file in blog folder for remove index.php

Comment: @DevidasKadam the client wants to redirect trafick from "domain.com" to "domain.com/blog" still after i commented out those lines, CodeIgniter works, but i MUST add the index.php that i Dont want it all :) Do you have any solution as how i can edit my .htaceess file. Or even better, can you post a sample code in new answer so i can upvote you too if it's fixed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I ended up removing the lines bellow from the .htaccess file inside the "root" folder

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Restarted Apache (no idea why this is necessary) and the new settings fixed everything...